# Why sudo does not work in a macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, sudo

I asked this question on mac rumors but as it's pretty developer specific no one could help so wondered if any developers here would know. Sometime in the last couple of weeks something happened that completely broke my sudo command. Now everytime I try to `sudo` anything it just comes up with a blank line. Nothing I can type into Terminal (or iTerm) does anything and I need to close the window.

[image]

I've got backups but don't know what files would have been broken and don't just want to reset my Mac to an arbitrary point in time and loose other work. I mostly just use sudo to edit `/private/etc/hosts` file and somehow now it's letting me edit and save that without sudo so I thought it might be stuck in sudo somehow but I've reset everything I can think of and haven't changed any settings that I know of.

I tried creating a new admin user and sudoing from that but it's the same.

I've tried following advice on various forums but none of them are working and I'm getting to the point I'm probably doing more damage to my mac. Anyone got any ideas of how to fix it or any files I can drag across from my backup that might fix it?

I've tried:

```
which sudo
```

and it comes up with `/usr/bin/sudo` which seems to be a valid file path.

Comment: Have you tried answers provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326194/sudo-hangs-without-prompting-for-password)?

Comment: I tried as many as I could - I couldn't do the mac equivalent of strace as it required sudo to run it. I can only think that an application I'm running changed a setting that broke it and it could only really be either codekit or ampps. I've looked for setting resets in these but can't find anything to fix it.

Comment: Seems like I'm not the only one. Seems like a very limited problem for some people on 10.12.4. I think that update is when it broke

https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2017/20170328_1326-macOS-10_12_4-sudo-broken.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following this link - https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2017/20170328_1326-macOS-10_12_4-sudo-broken.html - I found the solution and the problem. AMPPS had edited the sudoers file to include some NOPASSWD line which apparently doesn't work in 10.12.4. Commenting out those lines works

https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2017/20170407_1157-macOS-10_12_4-sudo-broken-fix.html

Comment: Turns out my initial suggestion was indeed right: you had a broken `/etc/sudoers` :-)

Comment: Yea that's what most of the online comments were saying - I just couldn't see it as it was only *broken* after the latest Mac update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a good idea to compare your current `/etc/sudoers` with an old version just in case.

Also, keep in mind the expect file permission is:

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Thanks, the permissions for that file is correct and I've compared it to the oldest sudoers file I have on backup and they're identical. I wouldn't have an idea if there's a mistake in the file but nothing has changed.

Comment: Ok, `sudoers` should be good then. BTW, have you tried running a simple `cmp` between `/usr/bin/sudo` binary and an old version? Just in case...

Comment: I just tried that but it won't let me - needs sudo permission - and I tried to just overwrite that binary with an old version but it also won't even let me delete it or even change the permissions on it. I think I might just have to wait for the next OS update and hope that it fixes whatever could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue for almost 3-4 months, It was bugging me a lot. It made me almost mad. Yesterday i decided to sit down and fix this issue once and for all.

After lot of reading and all, I found that AMPPS entry in sudoers file is culprit.

open sudoers file using `sudo visudo` command OR use some editor (take backup of sudoers file before making changes and also read guide to use "visodo" )

I commented 2 lines in my sudoers file and everything is fine now.

```
#%amit ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/AMPPS/Ampps.app
#%amit ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/AMPPS/ampps
```

Similar experience/solution has been shared by this blogger [here](https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2017/20170407_1157-macOS-10_12_4-sudo-broken-fix.html),

You might not be having AMPPS on your machine so what worked for me, might not work for you.

Point to highlight is **"There is something in there in your sudoers file which is causing issue, just find that line"**